# AWS ECS Fargate: The task failed to start due to: CannotPullContainerError: check schema1 manifest size has been retried 1 time(s):

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, mwaa

I am trying to run an AWS ECS task using Fargate with a private docker registry. I am using Fargate 1.40 version
I am getting the following error.

`The task failed to start due to: CannotPullContainerError: check schema1 manifest size has been retried 1 time(s): httpReadSeeker: failed open: content at https://myprivate.docker-registry.com/v2/images/manifests/sha256:784513647894125893258158712`

Any suggestions as to what this error could be?